# Basic d3: why can you select things that don't exist yet?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been learning about d3, and I'm a bit confused about selecting.  Consider the following example:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1021841

Specifically, let's look at this line:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("r", 8)
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i & 3); })
    .style("stroke", function(d, i) { return d3.rgb(fill(i & 3)).darker(2); })
    .call(force.drag)
    .on("mousedown", function() { d3.event.stopPropagation(); });
```

In the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections) it says, "A selection is an array of elements pulled from the current document."  I interpret this to mean that `svg.selectAll(.node)` creates an array of elements of class `.node` pulled from the current document, but as far as I can tell there are no such elements!  Unless I'm confused - and I'm almost certain that I am - the only place in the document where something is given the class "node" is after the selection has already occurred (when we write `.attr("class", "node")`).

So what is going on here?  What does `svg.selectAll(".node")` actually select?

Comment: the .enter().append() after the .data() is the one making the reference for it and then you work on that.

Comment: @HarshalCarpenter But what object is .data(nodes).enter().append() acting on?

Comment: .data(nodes) is applied on .selectAll(). Then, if selectAll(rect) does not find any 'rect', then .enter().append() makes the reference and then it works with .data().

Comment: @HarshalCarpenter OK, so if I write selectAll(blah) but d3 can't find any blah's in my document then the function returns a null object and then acts on the null object?  Is that correct?

Comment: Have a look at Mike Bostocks [*Thinking with Joins*](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/). It answers exactly this question.

Comment: @Paul yeah but as I worked on it, it generally does not work on null, it will throw an error as it is always expecting a real object(i mean not null object) to work. Null will have no properties to work on, so it will throw error such as, it does not have function .attr or anyother thng you might have attached , so we .enter() and .append() so that there is a DOM object to work on..

Comment: @altocumulus can you suggest me some books and links, I want to master  D3.js and I am very much interested in it ..

Comment: @altocumulus Indeed, that answered my question exactly - would you like to post a brief answer?

Comment: @HarshalCarpenter There are [so many](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials) of them. Reading through the tutorials mentioned on the first ten lines will give you a firm grip on the basic concepts and a thorough understanding of what's going on. You may then more easily shift to special techniques like geo data etc. Also have a look at and try to understand the [thousands of examples](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although, at first sight, this may look like a simple and silly question, the answer to it is probably the most important one for everyone trying to do some serious work with D3.js. Always keep in mind, that D3.js is all about binding data to some DOM structure and providing the means of keeping your data and the document in sync.

Your statement does exactly that:

1. Select all elements having class `node`. This may very well return an empty selection, as it is in your case, but it will still be a [`d3.selection`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections).
2. Bind data to this selection. Based on the above mentioned selection this will, on a per-element basis, compute a join checking if the new data is a) not yet bound to this selection, b) has been bound before, or c) was bound before but is not included in the new data any more. Depending on the result of this check the selection will be divided into an enter, an update, or an exit selection, respectively.
3. Because your selection was empty in the first place. All data will end up in the enter selection which is retrieved by calling `selection.enter()`.
4. You are now able to append your new elements corresponding to the newly bound data by calling `selection.append()` on the enter selection.

Have a look at the excellent article [*Thinking with Joins*](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) by Mike Bostock for a more in-depth explanation of what is going on.